# How to change image atributes right before an image to be saved?

Tags: images, hooks, media, save-post, meta-value

I have an installed plugin to import XML content, but it can't change some meta-data of the new image that will be saved.

For example, I'd like to intercept the action of saving an image BEFORE its saving and change many meta, like Title, Alt Text, Description, etc.

To be more specific, I'd like to:

1. Intercept the Wordpress actions right BEFORE an image is created
2. Obtain the current image data (title, alt, description, etc)
3. Change these data
4. Return the updated data to be saved

How to do this?

---

### Edit 1

I've tested the following code inside my current theme's `function.php`:

```
function my_sanitize_content($data, $postarr) {
    print_r ($data);
    print_r ($postarr);
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_attachment_data' , 'my_sanitize_content');
```

But when running the plugin it seems that `wp_insert_attachment_data` is not being executed, because **it shows nothing**.

If I use this instead:

```
function my_sanitize_content( $content ) {
    print_r ($content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post' , 'my_sanitize_content');
```

... the `print_r` **shows only the current `post_id`**.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. It is almost certainly a filter/hook that you want to use but I will have to leave it to other experts to help you identify which one(s).

Answer (score 0):

If the import function you're using uses `wp_insert_post()` *(used also by wp_insert_attachment())* to add the new images (attachment posts) to your site, then you could perhaps use the `wp_insert_attachment_data( array $data, array $postarr )` filter, which is defined inside `wp_insert_post()`.

According to the docs it,

> Filters attachment post data before it is updated in or added to the
>   database.

Parameters,

```
array $data    An array of sanitized attachment post data.
array $postarr An array of unsanitized attachment post data.
```

If you look at the `wp_insert_post()` docs, you can see what keys are present for the `wp_insert_attachment_data` parameters `$data` and `$postarr`, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

For attachments, if I remember correctly,

- title = post_title
- alt = '_wp_attachment_image_alt' post_meta
- caption = post_excerpt
- description = post_content

Comment: Thanks, but debugging `wp_insert_post()` parameters, it's giving only the newly created post ID, nothing more...

Comment: @RogérioDec I'm sorry, my answer was poorly worded. I mean if you look at the `wp_insert_post()` documentation you can see all the array keys that are in the `$postarr` parameter the function recieves. These same keys are, to my understanding, present in the `$data` and `$postarr` parameters the `wp_insert_attachment_data` filter recieves. The filter is used inside `wp_insert_post()` that's why I referenced the function in my answer. And it is the filter you need to use with `add_filter()`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and attention. I've updated the original post with more information, could you see it, please?